# Please create the [google-earth-engine] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[There are currently 3 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22earth+engine%22+is%3Aquestion) on GIS Stack Exchange referring to Google's Earth Engine. These are all tagged with other Google products ([google-earth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth), [google-earth-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-api), [google-maps-engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-engine)).

I request that the [google-earth-engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) tag be created for such questions. I have already created it [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/google-earth-engine), but I do not have the required reputation here.

(Disclosure: I am making this request on behalf of the Earth Engine development team.)

Comment: @AndreSilva Excerpt and minimal wiki suggested. That should be enough to get started, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else had already created the tag on one of those three questions but I added it to the other two and will set this to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Thank you. I have now also [suggested an edit to remove the unrelated tags](http://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69862) on one question; the other two seem OK or ambiguous as is.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case so I'm glad you suggested it - done!